# How do you tell if the current terminal session is in GNU screen?

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu, gnu-screen

I have a command I want to execute in `.bashrc` only when the current terminal
window is managed by GNU screen. How do I do this? Is there an environment variable for it? I used to have

```
if [ -n "$WINDOW" ]; then
    command
fi
```

But from what I can tell, `$WINDOW` may or may not be defined across all screen
managed sessions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell whether I'm in a screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392618/how-can-i-tell-whether-im-in-a-screen)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check for the environment variable $STY (contains info about the screen) or for $TERM being 'screen' (probably less reliable).

Comment: I've been using cargo cult scripts that used $TERM until now. Thanks for this! Just to make it even worse, some of the boxes the scripts run on have so old versions of bash that conditionals are limited (e.g. no partial matching)

Comment: `$STY` method doesn't work in a `sudo` script run inside a screen

Answer (score 5):

signine is correct

See the doc

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Environment.html

> `STY`
>
> Alternate socket name. If `screen` is invoked, and the environment variable `STY` is set, then it creates only a window in the running `screen` session rather than starting a new session.

Answer (score 4):

check `$TERM`, it is set to '`screen`' in screen session.. (but not 100% guaranteed)

**UPDATE**

alternatively, you can utilize the fact that in screen, `$TERMCAP` contains screen substring:

```
[[ $TERMCAP =~ screen ]] && echo "in screen"
```

*also not 100% guaranteed*

**UPDATE2**

if neither approach works, you can find some inspiration in [screen manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Environment)

Comment: Screen seems to inherit $TERM value from the terminal session launching it. So in my case it is xterm-256color and it depends on the environment. What I want is the general solution that can work under all environment.

Comment: The $TERMCAP approach applies to more cases, but misses cases where you SSH to other host under the same screen window, in which case $TERMCAP won't contain 'screen' substring. So, the applicability is exactly the same as $WINDOW, as it also loses its value once you ssh to other host. But all things equal, $WINDOW predicate works faster.

Comment: Right. That's what I meant by "applicability is exactly the same". I've been looking at the source code of GNU screen, and it looks like there is no solution to it. One could write a function to do ssh and then set a special environment variable, but that's not really elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest an alternative solution that is always visible and does not require checking to know you are inside a `screen` session.

Just add/edit a file `~/.screenrc` in your `$HOME` folder and add `caption` command:

```
caption always "%{= kc}Screen session on %H (system load: %l)%-28=%{= .m} %Y-%m-%d %0c"
```

and you will get at the very bottom one line that is always visible and colored.

```
Screen session on host (system load: 1.50 1.40 1.30)        2017-04-23 14:06
```

Please note:

> When you are inside screen on host1 and open another SSH session to host2 and open screen there which also has `.screenrc` you will get two lines at the bottom stacked from bottom up (like a wrapper).
>
> This is VERY useful in that case!
>
> `Screen session on host2 (system load: 0.01 0.03 0.05)            2017-04-23 14:14`
>   `Screen session on host1 (system load: 0.00 0.00 0.00)            2017-04-23 14:14`

---

Additional info:

> https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Caption.html
>
> > `Command: caption always|splitonly [string]`
>
> https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html#String-Escapes

---

> I found this hit [here](https://serverfault.com/a/656350/176452) on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Check variable $TERM