# how do you know your currently attached gnu screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

We used gnu screen a lot in the office and sometimes if I don't take note, I end up getting lost as to what screen session I already am in.

So my question is, how do you know what screen session you're in? Do you have a way to check?

CLARIFICATION: What I need to know is when I do a:

```
~$ screen -ls
```

and I see something like:

```
There is a screen on:
    4732.work_Sept42012     (Attached)
    3551.web01  (Attached)
    5521.mysql01 (Attached)
    1255.tomcat05 (Detached)
    3326.oracle15 (Attached)

 1 Socket in /tmp/uscreens/S-icasimpan.
```

How do I know if I am currently connected to any of the attached session?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/212392/how-to-include-screens-session-name-in-hardstatus) from superuser.com

Comment: @BurhanKhalid this is a good point but I wonder if there is screen generated info you can query. +1 for giving a helpful response :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell whether I'm in a screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392618/how-can-i-tell-whether-im-in-a-screen)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the `sessionname` screen command, screen sets the `STY` environment variable for processes it starts. You can check the value of this variable from a shell:

```
$ echo $STY
5521.mysql01
$
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Update:

`ctrl+a`, `:sessionname` can be used to display the name of the current screen session.

#### Previous reply (with missinterpreted question):

I struggled with this too until I came across the wonderful `hardstatus` feature. With these two lines in my `~/.screenrc` I get the following at the bottom of my screen sessions.

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kG}%-Lw%{= kW}%50> %n*%f %t%{= kG}%+Lw%< %{= kG}%-=%D %M %d | %C:%s %A %1`%{-}'
```

[image]

What I am looking at here is a screen session on my local computer with three windows (`bash`, `mumble`, `kalkyl`). In the active window called `mumble` I am connected to another computer over ssh on which I am running another screen session with three windows (`top`, `auto`, `bash`). I can see see all windows in both sessions and keep track of where I am.

Comment: The purpose of having the current time in the status line is to see whether the connection is live, i.e. if I get disconnected the time freezes.

Comment: your reply was helpful and I actually used it now in my .screenrc. I've added clarificatory statements to my question that you might have an answer too. +1 point for you too for being helpful :)

Comment: the ^A :sessionname method works when using sudo (or any other context that does not preserve the parent environment where $STY was set)